# Counting values from a list

Tags: r, list

I have a column whose observations are of type character and are organized as follows (example of output follows):

```
df <- data.frame(observation = c('["Extra pillows and blankets", "Dishes and silverware", "Room-darkening shades", "Hot water kettle", "Ethernet connection", "Wifi", "Dedicated workspace", "Oven"]',
                                 '["Extra pillows and blankets", "Dishes and silverware", "Room-darkening shades", "Hot water kettle", "Ethernet connection", "Wifi", "Dedicated workspace", "Oven"]',
                                 '["Extra pillows and blankets", "Dishes and silverware", "Room-darkening shades", "Hot water kettle", "Ethernet connection", "Wifi", "Dedicated workspace", "Oven"]'
))
```

My goal is to count the number of elements in each list of each observation (considering the separation of these elements by a comma in the list).
I've tried transforming it to a factor, to a list, I've used length and lengths, and many other things that I don't even remember. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution.

```r
m <- gregexpr(",", df$observation)
lengths(m) + 1L
#> [1] 8 8 8
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Or the one-liner

```r
lengths(strsplit(df$observation, ","))
#> [1] 8 8 8
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

But this creates a list before counting, which needs more memory and is slower. Maybe the first solution rewritten as a one-liner:

```
lengths(gregexpr(",", df$observation)) + 1L
```

Answer (score 2):

We can count the elements using `str_count()`:

Here we count the `,` and add 1 to get the count of elements:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(n_elements = str_count(observation, ",")+1)
```

```
1 ["Extra pillows and blankets", "Dishes and silverware", "Room-darkening shades", "Hot water kettle", "Ethernet connection", "Wifi", "Dedicated workspace", "Oven"]
2 ["Extra pillows and blankets", "Dishes and silverware", "Room-darkening shades", "Hot water kettle", "Ethernet connection", "Wifi", "Dedicated workspace", "Oven"]
3 ["Extra pillows and blankets", "Dishes and silverware", "Room-darkening shades", "Hot water kettle", "Ethernet connection", "Wifi", "Dedicated workspace", "Oven"]
  n_elements
1          8
2          8
3          8
```